# ASP.NET Core MVC view and edit PDF as filestream

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application that is creating a PDF and returning it to a view through a `FileStreamResult`. The view shows the PDF just fine however I need the user to be able to fill out the form in the PDF and then submit the file for saving. Ideally I would like to pass the filestream back to the controller for saving on the server side.

Embedded PDF in view

```
<embed src="@Url.Action("QC", new { jobnumber = Model.JobNumber, jobname = Model.JobName, customer = Model.Customer })" 
       width="100%" height="1000px"></embed>
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult QC(string jobnumber, string jobname, string customer)
{
    string file = new HelperFunctions().GenQCChecklist(jobnumber, jobname, customer);
    var fullfilename = Path.Combine(@"\\eplannas\AET-Projects\", file);
    var stream = new FileStream(fullfilename, FileMode.Open);
    var returnstream = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
    return returnstream;
}
```

I have also tried to pass the `FileStreamResult` directly to the view through a model however the embed does not seem to want to take my model as a src.

I know that I can generate a form for collecting the data and populating that to the PDF form however I would much rather have the user enter directly into the PDF.